# Handling Multiple Checkboxes ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have rendered a list of checkboxes and i am trying to setup an onChange which tracks the selected input and turns the value to `true`. But i keep getting an error message and also warning with needing a unique `key` even though i am passing the `index`.

This is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dust-gbjox?file=/src/App.js)

Please check this complete Code:-

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: [
      { name: "Check 1", value: false },
      { name: "Check 2", value: false },
      { name: "Check 3", value: false }
    ]
  };

  checkboxStateHandler = (event, idx) => {
    const { checkbox } = this.state;
    checkbox.checkboxes[idx] = event.target.checked;
    this.setState({
      checkbox
    });
  };

  renderCheckboxes = () => {
    return this.state.checkboxes.map((cb, index) => (
      <label>
        {cb.name}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          key={index}
          checked={cb.value}
          onChange={this.checkboxStateHandler}
        />
      </label>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderCheckboxes()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Tried to run your code, once I've clicked the first checkbox got undefined error for checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes needs to be done under `map` method,

-> Assign key to the immediate parent under map method and in your case it is `label`

```
 <label key={index}>
    ....
 </label>
```

-> Then you have to modify the `onChange` value like,

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 checked={cb.value}
 onChange={(e) => this.checkboxStateHandler(e,index)}
/>
```

Here the event and index needs to passed down as an arguments.

-> Then in `checkboxStateHandler` function get the parameters and assign the `event.target.checked` value to `checkboxes[idx].value`

```
  checkboxStateHandler = (event, idx) => {
    const { checkboxes } = this.state;
    checkboxes[idx].value = event.target.checked;
    this.setState({
      checkboxes
    });
  };
```

The above code will get rid of all warnings and errors.

> [**Forked codesandbox here..**](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dubinsky-6j4cj)

Comment: You are awesome. setting the key on label worked!! accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: [
      { name: "Check 1", value: false },
      { name: "Check 2", value: false },
      { name: "Check 3", value: false }
    ]
  };

  checkboxStateHandler = (event, idx) => {
    const { checkboxes } = this.state;
    checkboxes[idx] = {
        ...checkboxes[idx],
        value: event.target.checked,
    }
    this.setState({
      checkboxes
    });
  };

  renderCheckboxes = () => {
    return this.state.checkboxes.map((cb, index) => (
      <label>
        {cb.name}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          key={index}
          checked={cb.value}
          onChange={e => this.checkboxStateHandler(e, index)}
        />
      </label>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderCheckboxes()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

You must send the event and index to the method in order to change the value, also `checkboxStateHandler` needs a little changes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i am still getting the key issue, maybe i'll just try passing an id.

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick, For key issue you need to make ```key={index}``` to ```label``` and not ```input``` element.. Check my below answer and sandbox..